# Haskell: Draw tabulated data given header and rows as lists

Tags: haskell

I need to draw tabulated data given a header as list and rows as list of lists
This is what I came up with. I wouldn't say that I like it much.
Could you please have a look if it can be done better (I am sure it can) and generally point to any error and possible optimization. Maybe someone has done exact same thing before. Thanks.

```
import Data.Text (justifyLeft, unpack, pack)
import Data.Char (toUpper)

tDraw :: [String] -> [[String]] -> IO()
tDraw h rs = do
  putChar '\n'
  -- draw header
  mapM_ (\x -> putStr x) header
  putChar '\n'
  -- draw separator line
  mapM_ (\x -> putChar x) (replicate (cell * length header) '=')
  putChar '\n'
  -- draw rows
  mapM_ (\x -> row cell x) rs
  where
    cell = if l < 10 then 12 else l + 2
           where l = (maximum . map (\x -> length x) . concat) (h:rs)
    header = map (\x -> strToUp $ unpack $ justifyLeft cell ' ' (pack x)) h
             where strToUp = map (\c -> toUpper c)
    row n l  = do
      mapM_ (\x -> putStr $ unpack $ justifyLeft n ' ' (pack x)) l
      putChar '\n'
```

Comment: A quick fixup: `(\ x -> foo x)` is identical to just `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

It might make sense to use a pretty-printing library to do this.  You can use [pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty) along with the extension [pretty-ncols](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-ncols) package; or possibly [boxes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes) would work as it's aimed at more 2D textual information.